# Reservation System Impediments

Tags: javascript, html

Dearest people of overflow,

For a project we had to make a reservation system for a theater in the Netherlands.
The idea is that we make a reservation system based on the theater seat map in which 
prices differ depending on the seat and row, made in JavaScript. We actually made the map and got the arrays as clickable elements. Now we found a few problems. 1. the seat class 0, isnt actually a class or shouldnt be clickable. we used it to fill the map, but dont actually know how to get it out of the script but made it transparent in the CSS file. 2. we need some sort of table which displays the seats which are selected and counts it up if you click multiple. we got extremely stuck and would extremely appreciate some help. 
Kind regards,

Wessel Olde Olthof

```
<script>
var room1 = [
//   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2
[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],//14
[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],//13
[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],//12
[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1],//11
[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1],//10
[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,2,2,1,1,1],//9
[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,2,2,1,1,1],//8
[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,2,2,1,1,1],//7
[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,2,2,1,1,1],//6
[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1],//5
[0,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,0],//4
[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],//3
[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],//2
[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],//1
]; 

function make_seat()
{
for(var r = 0 ; r < room1.length ; r++)
{

        var rowdiv = document.createElement("div");

        rowdiv.setAttribute("id","DIV_" + r);
        for(s = 0 ; s < room1[r].length ; s++)
        {

            var seat = document.createElement("button");



                seat.setAttribute("id","seat_" + r + "_" + s);

                seat.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
                //seat.addEventListener("click",reservation,false);


                seat.setAttribute("onclick","order("+r+","+s+")");

                switch(room1[r][s])
            {
                case 0 : seat.setAttribute("class","seat_0"); break;
                case 1 : seat.setAttribute("class","seat_1"); break;
                case 2 : seat.setAttribute("class","seat_2"); break;
                case 3 : seat.setAttribute("class","seat_3"); break;
            }
            rowdiv.appendChild(seat);

        }

    document.getElementById("DIV_inhoud").appendChild(rowdiv);
 }

 }


function order(r,s)
{
alert("row = " + (r + 1) + " seat = " + (s + 1));
}

function reservation(ev)
{
ev = ev || window.event;
var x = ev.target || ev.srcElement;

alert(x.id);
}

function start()
{
make_seat();
//document.getElementById("BTN_plus").addEventListener("click",optellen,false);
//document.getElementById("BTN_maal").addEventListener("click",vermenigvuldigen,false);
}

window.addEventListener("load",start,false);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<DIV id = DIV_inhoud></DIV>
```

Answer (score 2):

I put together a jsfiddle, which hopefully does what you want. Since I use jQuery, I opted to just use it here, if you are just starting, it is probably worth a look since it makes a whole bunch of things easier (or any other js library for that matter).

http://jsfiddle.net/Moritz_M/kcu5ypka/16/

```
var room1 = [
//   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], //14
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], //13
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], //12
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], //11
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], //10
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], //9
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], //8
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], //7
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], //6
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], //5
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], //4
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], //3
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], //2
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], //1
];

function make_seat() {
for (var r = 0; r < room1.length; r++) {

    var rowdiv = $("<div>");

    rowdiv.attr("id", "DIV_" + r);
    for (s = 0; s < room1[r].length; s++) {

        var seat = $("<button id='seat_"+r+"_"+s+"'>");

        seat.attr("id", "seat_" + r + "_" + s);

        // seat.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
        //seat.addEventListener("click",reservation,false);


        seat.click(order);
        switch (room1[r][s]) {
            case 0:
                seat.attr("class", "seat_0");
                break;
            case 1:
                seat.attr("class", "seat_1");
                break;
            case 2:
                seat.attr("class", "seat_2");
                break;
            case 3:
                seat.attr("class", "seat_3");
                break;
        }
        rowdiv.append(seat);

    }

   $("#DIV_inhoud").append(rowdiv);
}

}


function order() {
    var seatInfo = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
    var r = seatInfo[1];
    var s = seatInfo[2];
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    $("#count_seat_1").html($(".seat_1.selected").size());
    $("#count_seat_2").html($(".seat_2.selected").size());
    $("#count_seat_3").html($(".seat_3.selected").size());
    $("#count_total").html($(".selected").size());
}

function reservation(ev) {
    ev = ev || window.event;
    var x = ev.target || ev.srcElement;

    alert(x.id);
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    make_seat();
    //document.getElementById("BTN_plus").addEventListener("click",optellen,false);
    //document.getElementById("BTN_maal").addEventListener("click",vermenigvuldigen,false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your work!I can definitly continou my work now! Greatly appreciated ^^